# Set the name attribute of the pathlib Path class

Tags: python, pathlib

I was wondering if there was a neat way to set the Path.name attribute.

My code basically looks like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
mypath = Path("this/is/a/path")
mypath.name == "path"
>>> True
#now I want to change the name, or the top level folder name in the path
mypath.name = "panda" #does not work, since its a property

#only way I can think of:
mypath = mypath.parent.joinpath("panda")
```

this is pretty ugly, especially since I am actually in a class with longer names for everything. Is there a setter for the name attribute? I cant find any, but I also didnt find the opposite...

Comment: From the documentation: **Paths are immutable and hashable.** You can't change the name, you have to create a new Path object that derives from the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [with_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) method which would be cleaner and exactly what the method is designed for.

However, it is not overwriting the `name` attribute which is impossible because it is immutable. It returns a new Path object so you will have overwrite `mypath` or save it as something new.

```
mypath = mypath.with_name('panda')
```